# prevent textbox from accepting string and allow numbers , delete key and the back and next key

Tags: c#-4.0, event-handling

Which C# Code Can I Use to prevent textbox from accepting string and allow numbers , backspace key ,the (dot)key and the back and next key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, for example in `Form_Load`

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += (obj, args) =>
{
    Keys[] allowedKeys = { Keys.Back, Keys.Next, Keys.Delete, Keys.OemPeriod, Keys.Left, Keys.Right };
    args.SuppressKeyPress = !allowedKeys.Contains(args.KeyCode) && (args.KeyValue < 48 || args.KeyValue > 57);
};
```

Comment: thanks, it works very good in All except :
when i want to move between the numbers using the arrow left or right

Comment: @fawzymokhtar: Then add `Keys.Left, Keys.Right` (edited my answer)